# Using NavigationService without XAML files

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create some pages in my Windows Phone application without the use of any XAML. Everything is working, however, I'm failing to use NavigationService/ Journal with this approach and all my attempts to utilize it are answered by the usual "No XAML was found at the location {0}'" response. Yes, I can add an almost empty XAML file to get everything working, but is this kind of boiler plate code really necessary?

Is it maybe possible to use the UriMapping to map certain Uris to specific classes instead of *.xaml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS did a couple of very sloppy and blatantly wrong design "choices" by forcing programmers to use XAML at any cost and therefore creating WP apps or even navigating in those apps without XAML is not possible (yet?). I have high hopes their interns are going to fix this during their next semester ...

Answer (score 0):

Even with UriMapping, you'll have to use a valid XAML page. And cancelling the navigation in the Navigating event will prevent the page to be added to the back stack. So using a dummy page is probably the best way if you want to be able to use the navigation service and the journal.

Comment: Even tried accessing the BackStack directly, but everything is locked down (internal, private) and cannot be changed via Reflection on WP. They even made JournalEntry sealed and the constructor internal. Otherwise this would allow for setting the RootFrame content and simply adding an entry on the BackStack manually. I think one way of doing without XAML could be by handling NavigationFailed (Frame) events and maintaining a custom BackStack manually.

Comment: But if you start creating pages from scratch without using XAML, maybe you can handle the back key pressed event, and simulate a back stack.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is I guess against the WindowsPhone guidelines and hence your app may get rejected from the market place.. please verify on this first

Comment: The Windows Phone marketplace team is rejecting apps, because the XAML/ c# ratio is not to their liking? They must have some fierce XML enthusiasts in their midst to do so :) Sorry, but I simply prefer strongly typed, inheritable, readable, fast, modern and object oriented code with excellent IDE support. Regarding UriMapping and NavigationService: I do understand that with WP I'm first and foremost an unpaid developer for MS and their ecosystem and that nobody really own's his own phone/hardware. So if Simon says do it his way, I simply have to, but where did you found this?